# Connect simultaneously to mobile internet connection and wireless

Tags: networking, wireless, internet, webcam, mobile-broadband

I have 4 ip cameras streaming to a local network, using a wireless router. I need to access these cameras from Ubuntu. This works fine when I am connected to the local network, but on the same PC I need to use a mobile internet connection to connect to the internet.

How can I connect simultaneously to mobile internet connection to use the internet and to my local wireless for viewing my IP webcams?

Comment: What problems did you face?

Answer (score -2):

usually one physical wifi-adapter can only connect to one network at the same time... USUALLY, maybe you've a special one?!
if not you'll need a second (physical) wifi-adapter (connected by usb or whatever)... then you can connect to a second one.

Comment: "mobile Internet"  = different device, I'd say.

Comment: hmmm I've misunderstood the question... but now I don't see the problem connecting to both. Please explain you problem in detail (software you use, screenshot, error messages..)

Comment: You might want to add your comment to the question :-)